# Zend Framework - DisplayGroup inside DisplayGroup

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

Is this possible to do with display groups in Zend Framework?
other ideas on how to do this?

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>DisplayGroupOuter</legend>
    <label for="outer">Outer</label> 
    <input type="text" name="outer" id="outer"/>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>DisplayGroupInner</legend>
      <label for="inner">Inner</label> 
      <input type="text" name="inner" id="Inner"/>
    </fieldset>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Zend view scripts](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.scripts.html)? This allows you more control over the layout of your html form, and should allow you to embed your fieldsets as you like.